# How to convert Python datetime in JSON format?

Tags: python, json

How do I convert Python DateTime in JSON format?

input

```
from datetime import datetime
my_date = datetime.now()
```

output

```
{
   "start_date": '2020-05-06T09:27:51.386383'
}
```

Comment: You don't mention initial/input string. We can only speculate about it

Comment: Dates aren't put into "JSON format". It's just a string. Also, you're being downvoted here because date formatting and parsing is 1) answered before 2) documented enough in the python docs 3) you've not specified an exact format, so are we supposed to guess ISO8601?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't use a datetime object directly in the JSON, you'll need to convert it to a string format first before you can use it.

Use [strftime](http://strftime.org/) to convert datetime object to string.

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime                                                                                                              

In [2]: {'start_date': datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')}                                                                            
Out[2]: {'start_date': '2021-01-27T11:10:00.489530'}
```